# Fixing show hide blocks

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code to hide show blocks. When clicking show it display all blocks. How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#hide").click(function(){$(".block").hide();});
    $("#show").click(function(){$(".block").show();});
  
});
```

```css
.block{background: grey; width: 350px; height: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>

<div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a unique ID for both and it will solve your problem:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button id="show1">Show</button>
<div id="block1">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="hide1">Hide</button>
</div>

<div>
<button id="show2">Show</button>
<div id="block2">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="hide2">Hide</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#hide1").click(function(){$("#block1").hide();});
            $("#show1").click(function(){$("#block1").show();});
            $("#hide2").click(function(){$("#block2").hide();});
            $("#show2").click(function(){$("#block2").show();});

        });
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/ox9mbr70/

Answer (score 3):

Try this : You are using same `id` (`show` and `hide`) multiple times, change this to `class`. Bind click event using class `show` or `hide`. Also, just show or `div` with `class="block"` which is next to clicked button and not all. Same for hide action, hide only previous div with `class="block"`. See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("button.hide").click(function(){$(this).prev(".block").hide();});
    $("button.show").click(function(){$(this).next(".block").show();});
  
});
```

```css
.block{background: grey; width: 350px; height: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class="show">Show</button>
<div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>

<div>
<button class="show">Show</button>
<div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different id and classes for every div and button

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide1").click(function(){$(".block1").hide();});
   $("#show1").click(function(){$(".block1").show();});
   $("#hide2").click(function(){$(".block2").hide();});
   $("#show2").click(function(){$(".block2").show();});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should be unique. Use class instead or different IDs.

And you can use `$(this).next();` to play with the next `.block` element or `$(this).prev();` with the previous one instead of all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector selects all the elements of class `block`. You only want to select the ones inside the parent of the clicked button. Like so:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){$(this).parent().children(".block").hide();});
$("#show").click(function(){$(this).parent().children(".block").show();});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to have multiple objects with same `id`. Instead try using `class`.

You can traverse the parent and find it's content to show or hide. Check below answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".block").hide();
  });
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".block").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  background: grey;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
  <button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="block">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
  <button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```